# Estimate on $\alpha$-Hölder norm of path signature

Tags: rough-paths

Let $N \geq \lfloor 1/\alpha \rfloor > 0$ and consider a weakly geometric $\alpha$-Hölder rough path $\textbf{x}$ that preserves the origin, i.e. an element $\textbf{x} \in C^{\alpha\text{-Höl}}_o([0,T],G^{\lfloor 1/\alpha \rfloor}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. This is standard notation, and is the one in the book "Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths: Theory and Applications" by Peter Friz and Nicolas Victoir.

It is well know that there exists a unique Lyons lift of order $N$, i.e for each $\textbf{x} \in C^{\alpha\text{-Höl}}_o([0,T],G^{\lfloor 1/\alpha \rfloor}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ there exists a unique
$$S_N(\textbf{x}) \in C^{\alpha\text{-Höl}}_o([0,T],G^{N}(\mathbb{R}^d)).$$
See Theorem 9.5 in the book above for a more precise statement. My question is about the estimates that one gets. In particular, we know that there exists a constant $C(N,\alpha)$ such that
$$||S_N(\textbf{x})||_{\alpha\text{-Höl};[s,t]} \leq C(N,\alpha) ||\textbf{x}||_{\alpha\text{-Höl};[s,t]}.$$
The estimate above holds for every $N$. But what about the whole signature? Specifically, let $S_\infty(\textbf{x})$ denote the entire signature associated to $\textbf{x}$. Can we bound the $\alpha$-Hölder norm of $S_\infty(\textbf{x})$ with $||\textbf{x}||_{\alpha\text{-Höl};[s,t]}$? In other words, can we obtain the estimate above with $S_N$ substituted by $S_\infty$?

Comment: Are you considering the homogenous norm or inhomogenous "norm"?

Comment: I am considering the Carnot-Caratheodory norm (hence homogenous) over $G^N(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: Which is the one considered in Theorem 9.5 as well, if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we see this by following their definition of $C$ in the proofs.

In lemma 9.2, they bound in (9.1) by $\frac{2^{N}}{(N+1)!}\ell^{N+1}=B_{N}\ell^{N+1}$. This $B_{N}\to 0$ as $N\to +\infty$. Then in the proof of 9.3, they use this same constant $B_{N}$ a couple of times due to the four triangle inequality arguments. So at worst we get some $(cB_{N})^{a}$ for constants $c,a>0$. They also use there the constant $C_{N,p}=1/(1-2^{1-(N+1)/p})\to 1$. So overall all the constants are bounded as $N\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I understand your reasoning, but I'd like to point out that in the proof the authors end up proving the estimate for consecutive signature levels, i.e. they bound the $p-$variation norm of $S_{N+1}(x)$ with the $p-$variation norm of $S_{N}(x)$. If one now considers the situation of the inequality (9.2) for N arbitrarily larger than $[p]$, then we have to compound the constants. Do you reckon this changes anything?

Comment: @Oscar yes I should have mentioned that. Here we benefit from the factorial term (N+1)! beating any exponential.

Comment: Makes sense! However, I've been trying to make the estimates of Lemma 9.2 and Proposition 9.3 explicit as a function of $N$, and in the end I obtain a constant C that goes to $0$ as $N\to \infty$. This cannot be, clearly. I still think your reasoning is correct, but I confess I'm struggling with making the dependency on $N$ explicit.

Comment: @Oscar I will try to return to their exposition, but in the meantime how about simply using prop 2.4. from https://fabricebaudoin.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/rough.pdf and summing over all of them to bound $S_{\infty}$ by omega. That puts into context the factorial decay.

Comment: as explained in pg47 https://ilyachevyrev.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/thesis-templated.pdf, this implies that the infinite signature has the same bound.

Comment: I will try to flesh out those arguments in the post.

Comment: @Oscar Even in Friz-Victoir, the way I understand it is that we write a telescoping sum $$S_{\infty}=\sum_{N} S_{N+1}-S_{N}$$
and then use that decaying factorial bound.

Comment: I believe that in the thesis of Ilya, at least in page 47, the bound holds for geometric paths in the unit ball.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, big thanks to @ThomasKojar for taking the time to provide some insight on this matter. I will post an answer here in an attempt to make the aforementioned estimates explicit in terms of $N$. Once this is solved, I'll mark the original post of @ThomasKojar as an answer, thus closing this thread.

In the following, I'll use the same notation as in the book "Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths: Theory and Applications" by Peter Friz and Nicolas Victoir. This post pertains to Proposition 9.3. The goal is to show that, for all $N \geq [p]$ and $x\in C^{1\text{-var}}([0,T],\mathbb{R}^d)$, we have
$$||S_{N+1}(x)||_{p\text{-var};[s,t]} \leq C \ ||S_N(x)||_{p\text{-var};[s,t]},$$
while making the dependency of $C$ on $N$ explicit.

**1)** I'll jump directly to the first bound in the original proof. Namely, estimate (9.4). Here we obtain that
$$|\Gamma_{s,u} - (\Gamma_{s,t} + \Gamma_{t,u})| \leq \frac{2}{(N+1)!} l^{N+1} \leq \frac{2 \ c(p)}{(N+1)!} \ \omega(s,u)^{\frac{N+1}{p}}.$$

> In the second inequality I'm not really sure how to justify bounding $l$ with $\omega(s,u)^{1/p}$, but I'm confident that the constant arising from this second estimate only depends on $p$, hence the notation $c(p)$. All in all, the constant $c_2$ in the book is given by

$$c_2 = \frac{2 \ c(p)}{(N+1)!}$$

**2)** The next step is straightforward, being a direct application of Lemma 9.2. We have that
$$|\Gamma_{s,t}| \leq \frac{2}{(N+1)!} \ |x|^{N+1}_{1\text{-var};[s,t]},$$
and thus, the constant $c_3$ in the book is given by
$$c_3 = \frac{2}{(N+1)!}.$$

**3)** Then, by a direct application of Lemma 6.2 we have that
$$|\Gamma_{s,t}| \leq \frac{c_2}{1 - 2^{1 - \frac{N+1}{p}}} \ \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}},$$
hence,
$$c_4 = c_2 = \frac{2 \ c(p)}{(N+1)!}.$$

**4)** Afterwards, by yet another triangle inequality argument we have
\begin{align*}
|\pi_{N+1}(\textbf{y}_{s,t})| \leq& \frac{c_2}{1 - 2^{1 - \frac{N+1}{p}}} \ \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}} + |\pi_{N+1}(S_{N+1}(x^{s,t})_{s,t})| \leq \\
\leq& \frac{c_2}{1 - 2^{1 - \frac{N+1}{p}}} \ \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}} + \frac{1}{(N+1)!} \left( \int_s^t |dx^{s,t}| \right)^{N+1} \leq\\
\leq& \frac{c_2}{1 - 2^{1 - \frac{N+1}{p}}} \ \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}} + \frac{1}{(N+1)!} \ c'(p) \ \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}} = \\
=& \frac{1}{(N+1)!} \left( \frac{2 c(p)}{1 - 2^{1 - \frac{N+1}{p}}} + c'(p) \right) \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}} \leq\\
\leq& \frac{c''(p)}{(N+1)!} \left(1 + C_{N,p} \right) \omega(s,t)^{\frac{N+1}{p}}
\end{align*}

> Here, like before, I'm not sure how we are bounding the length of the path $x^{s,t}$ with the control $\omega$, but I'm confident that the constant that pops out doesn't depend on $N$. Hence the notation $c'(p)$ and $c''(p)$.

**5)** Now, apparently it's sufficient to use the equivalence of norms. I get that we want the Carnot-Caratheodory norm but I'm not understanding how to get the upper bound of $||\textbf{y}_{s,t}||$.

Feel free to edit this post!